# Remove first encountered elements from a second list

Tags: code-golf, array

*Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991478/remove-first-encountered-elements-from-a-list) on Stackoverflow.*

---

#### The task

Let's have two lists/arrays of integers: `L1` and `L2` of equal length. You need to identify in `L2` the position of first occurrence of each number and remove from `L1` the values on the corresponding positions. Then print/output the modified `L1`.

Any reasonable input/ouput format is accepted as long as the lists are distinguishable.

#### Example

```
L1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
L2 = [2 3 3 5 5 4 3 7 1]
First occurence of each number in L2:
L2 = [2 3 3 5 5 4 3 7 1]
      ^ ^   ^   ^   ^ ^
Corresponding elements to remove from L1:
L1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
      ^ ^   ^   ^   ^ ^
Output result:
[3 5 7]
```

#### Test cases

```
Input -- Output
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];[2,3,3,5,5,4,3,7,1] -- [3,5,7]
[1,1,1];[1,2,3] -- []
[2,2,2];[1,1,1] -- [2,2]
[-1,0,2,123456];[-1,0,-1,0] -- [2,123456]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40];[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] -- [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9856/55372)

Comment: [An answer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991706/2045384) under the SO question is [53 bytes after rename variables and remove spaces](https://tio.run/##rU/LasQwELv3K3xMQIXMjJ3HQr8k64NDE2roZpeQLvTrU21goc25DBgsjTTS7Xv9uM62TW/n7TNdhvfkEoZTf3fTdXEZd5dnN85fl3FJ61ikMk9u6HMkOvSnHON2W/K8FlPRCxQGj4AaDVp0Ef0DMSKBuBGVWJYvvxQcbu3KP4wS0Z2Rg@ZVUJEUNR9qbuz/x3NwPmSBVBB6UWkQDwmQGsJELaSD0pMaHjWohwZoDW2gLbSDVTCB0ZJtWCTAalgDa2EdfPUM@n/DMtsP).

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: @xgoi yes, non-empty too.

Comment: @pajonk I retracted my close vote already, but I forgot to delete the comment. I voted to close because the Jelly answer for both is identical, but I didn't read this question properly and didn't see it had a second input. (The Jelly answers differ in number of arguments, and happen to be the same code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒQ¬Tị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opMBDa0Ie7u7@//9/tJGOMRCaAqEJkDbXMYz9H22oAxI1AYqZAUUsdCxj/wMA)

### Explanation

```
ŒQ¬Tị   Main dyadic link
ŒQ      Distinct sieve - replace first occurences with 1 and other occurences with 0
  ¬     Negate
   T    Get the indices with truthy elements
    ị   Index into the other array
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

A cool new approach from [@kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops), which outputs by modifying the input.

```python
def f(a,b):
 while b:b.pop()in b or a.pop(len(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY9NasMwEIX3PsXsIsFL8Iz8m5Ab5AYmFJs6xODaInUaenp35MSrbksRCM2b7z3N@O/pOg4yz@/thS6mRmP3ET2uXd9Ss292fvTGdgM1NN6oXsq@HUxj7fyEWPFu8KDxPnk60q1@vGl9n4zdffq@m8yGtlva2IhODDqJMh@1N@1X3SM4V@qwscq8UkLXhLdKF6PGk@jL37ph0hg6HhdwrhgChwQpMuQoUJ4PVVCcKqnqTlU@hwGqIOXnSC16FFusz5aqopUsKq@GIETVlhFrj8UlaabAUodrhV6d6Pcs4Biscco4cAJOwRlYJyrAJURz1aPfOEgCSSEZJIcUkBIuhmM4jdRtdJEULoPL4Qq4Ekm8zvp3Z13oH3f4AQ)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[x for x in a[::-1]if b.pop()in b][::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY/daoNAEIXvfYq5i8IxOLv@B98gb2ClrDQSweiSmiZ9ejtr4lVvSxlYdr45Z37s93yeRrV01dsymEv7YcigLesHddOVHtSPZOqyDLnpO2r3drJ@IKxtnnC5n/vhRFx6orSg6TZbquhq7u@S32Y/2H/aoZ/9HYUh7QKPjgw6KtFcjPVPX2aAc26qwy4QzauLq/ruL8he@3Gmzn/aA6qqVbXUDAWNGAlSZMhRNIfaES0kEa6FcuOm1w5ljScWCZGt1mdJqJJMrZQ3gwNeHTIiqbHScZKKYM3ds4leFe/3LuAILO1Eo8ExOAGnYNkoBxdQ0lc8MkZDxVAJVAqVQeVQBXQEzdDSUq6RQxLoFDqDzqELxNG269/FdtA/3vAD)

We can determine whether an element stays in `L1` by whether the corresponding element in `L2` is its first occurrence. This is done with `b.pop()in b`, which pops the last element from `L2` and checks if it still exists in the list.

Because we process the elements in reverse, `[::-1]` needs to be used twice. It makes the final code a lot larger than I had hoped, but I am not able to come up with a shorter approach.

Comment: That's clever.. nicely done.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##vY9NasMwEIX3PsXsIsFL8Iz8m5Ab5AYmFJs6xODaInUaenp35MSrbksRCM2b7z3N@O/pOg4yz@/thS6mRmP3ET2uXd9Ss292fvTGdgM1NN6oXsq@HUxj7fyEWPFu8KDxPnk60q1@vGl9n4zdffq@m8yGtlva2IhODDqJMh@1N@1X3SM4V@qwscq8UkLXhLdKF6PGk@jL37ph0hg6HhdwrhgChwQpMuQoUJ4PVVCcKqnqTlU@hwGqIOXnSC16FFusz5aqopUsKq@GIETVlhFrj8UlaabAUodrhV6d6Pcs4Biscco4cAJOwRlYJyrAJURz1aPfOEgCSSEZJIcUkBIuhmM4jdRtdJEULoPL4Qq4Ekm8zvp3Z13oH3f4AQ) by output via modifying input

Comment: @kops Thanks! I almost never see this trick in Python, so it's nice to see it put to good use.

Answer (score 9):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
/⍨∘~∘≠
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=03/Uu@JRx4w6IH7UuQAA&f=rY4xCsJAEEV7T2EXhS9mZnY3CbmBhRaWIa0eQqyEgAFFC3ux8gJewKPsSfwJsbGWgWX2/fnzZxubyy6eb4v1ahnbw2Y@9O9nUiaTeLzHtontYxpPr/0oNtcthUqgMDh4BGTIUdRl1REj8eRGKnUy7iZZVHtHT5Sd9kSGmZkgJRQ15wOV/t89w4afLEgKoZcOgziIhwQIE3NIAeUuehhiUAf10ADNoDm0gKUwgXElr@WhHhZgGSyHFXDp97D/VZ18AA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A function submission which takes L1 on the left and L2 on the right.

-2 bytes from Bubbler.

### Explanation

```
/⍨∘~∘≠
/⍨     remove elements from L! identified by:
   ~   the bitwise negation of
     ≠ unique mask of L2
```

Comment: `/⍨∘~∘≠` also works.

Comment: I mistakenly thought it'd infer as reduce. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```hs
f[]
f z(a:s)(b:t)=[a|b`elem`z]++f(b:z)s t
f _[]_=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY/NboMwEITvPMUeIoHVoY1tIL/01EulvIGLGichKSoBBD5FffbSJQ299FpVli37m9nx7pvt3vOy7ItzU7eOnqyz95uic94pfemPJvOOdAnsshPBbulEauzHbpuX@Xl7ye7ujgwvoiPHrleTvaYm68@2qNJD7REFpfTRinXYNbYKHlJ/5Yv15PGUu01R5Wwoc8cm5aP2BaU02sgXwaGtG5LUilUpWWpzeyCOWy7Nc@WyVal@oPqB9ci@qyPi2JvGnzVtUTmaUHDiIBoCUqrBd94Kw/UmCDYPQ/RGQkEjQowEM8yxyFZmIJpJzFwzlRmFIZkBzTKPS3ix7Vr6LTFV/FJXKseCAXgmlJiyJpWO4oQN1/dwjKab4v3uBXIKyXHs0ZARZAyZQHJHc8gFFOdyDX@joSKoGCqBmkHNoRbQU2gJzZE8DQ8SQyfQM@g59ALRdOz179Y40D/O8Lk/lvbU9eG@ab4A)

The solution is the anonymous function which calls `f` applied to the empty list: `f[]`. `f` keeps track of which elements of L2 we've seen already and only adds the corresponding element of L1 to the result if we haven't seen L2's head yet.

`import Data.List` for the builtins turns out to be too expensive:

#### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
((map fst.((\\)<*>nubBy((.snd).(==).snd))).).zip
import Data.List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/LboMwEEX3fMUsImFXFxrbPPIii6qbSv0DwoIGQlEJIKCL9uNLB/KQqgoZjc@9cz3znvYfeVWN5bltuoGe0yF1X8t@sIroMApxTls69YMrxOEgdw/7@vPt6UsIt68z6YooknMlpSvd77K1HOdvynhOyzrKGotIVMpGJ3dO36a1eIzsrS13i32RD69lnbOhygc2aRuNLSmim41sKbKuaUlRJ7eVYqnL04w4brOJX@oh2Vb6DvUdNjd26faIY68aP9Z2ZT3QgkTBQTQFRNSAaz4aU3kVJJunJcZYQcPAg48AIVZYJ9t4IoaJz9wwVQk5DsUTChOLW/hj29x6kZhqvumZqlvDBKzYUViyprTx/IAN83363UxXxfo/C9QSiuPYY6A8KB8qgOKJVlBraM7lHn7GQHvQPnQAHUKvoNcwSxgFw5G8DS/iwwQwIcwKZg1veZn153iq0qIfnWPb/gI)

#### How?

```hs
((map fst.((\\)<*>nubBy((.snd).(==).snd))).).zip
                                             zip -- zip the lists
           (\\)                                  -- delete from the zipped lists
                  nubBy                          -- the first occurence of each element under the equivalence class defined by:
                        ((.snd).(==).snd)        -- equality of the second element of each pair
  map fst                                        -- take the first element of each pair from the resulting list
```

and then a lot of punctuation to send the right arguments to the right places...

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(x,y)x[duplicated(y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoMwDEXf9xUFXxqI0tQ6UfYnpQ@jWhCGE1HQr@9S3WBsuZDAvSfJHIO45TGso1@G5yg33GGz3To9Bn9f@k7u4GKQ1DbopcaSVbEMzxoJQByV2WTX7hKkl4QsQGrLd/pdmT0hjSzADw0/EIcnlxMqRkmXprom/jBS453EnUmCqTUK537ik0YB/H/WoiiEUS6@AA)

A rare case, where obscure `duplicated` function appears to be useful...

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
#~1-~:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsJADETvfsVgD9tCtphNt60LngRPnvwBD2KQXvyD/vqa7aoME8i8DGTJ@94pTgkOhAOS2fc4366X3Kzs15S73fPxekMQMcEntEyBhAaKNNJEMx07KNqSiWXRiFjO355zpcSb1BwgFQSTkbBJ68WPcJAhjgXf2T76B1r3MvIH)

Filter by `#~` the complement of `1-` the nub sieve `~:`

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe ...but now outgolfed by [Kirill L's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223575/95126)*

```r
function(a,b)a[match(b,b)<seq(!b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZDBasMwEETv/gqXXCQYg3dXkm1Iv6SUYAuH5hCHOE5@312lpTXUhx5CEAgxu29Ws@M89sfTrd/tD@Nl2vVDfJ331yFOh9NgWnS2fTu2U/wwnb63l/5sXjr7/gcy0RAYAgePgAo1GotokiQqeS2IymRtvsmLIo8myZXNVp30JPpu@UusNrP28FczLe2TutZfEEpFiMX5kLi7kK4l@13O/pMTVIJ0tlICciAPCiANW4MasI5TRv8jYAf24ACuwDW4gZQQgqilLkp35CEBUkFqSANX/iR73FnmfGKQbP4E)

`match(x,y)` finds the index of the first element in `y` equal to each element of `x`.

So, `match(b,b)` is equal to the index of each element if it's the first one with a particular value, otherwise it it'll be equal to an earlier index where that value was previously encountered.

`seq(!b)` is golfy shorthand for `seq_along(b)`, and returns a sequence of integers `1...b` (in other words, the indices of each element of `b`).  Note that we need the `!` because `seq` defaults to outputting a sequence of `b` integers if `b` contains only a single numeric element;   therefore, we use `!` to first convert the argument to a `logical`-type vector (where this can't happen).

Answer (score 6):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
{a[++n]=b[$1]++}n>FNR&&a[++m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnJ@Saqv@vzoxWls7L9Y2KVrFMFZbuzbPzs0vSE0NJJob@1@dKzU5I19B3VDBSMFYwUTBVMFMwVzBQsFSXcFOwccQKguSMwbKmQJVGAPlDcGyRlyJ5dkKumUKQcG26grqCkoqICuVgBJAnf8B) *(Thanks very much to [Jonah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah) for the TIO link)*

Takes input as two files L1 and L2, with one number per line in each (or, with the `-v RS=' '` option, space-separated on a single line).

Comment: Clever idea to store the list of numbers as one per line!  I had to read this a few times to figure it out. :)

Comment: @cnamejj - On re-reading I realized that it's accidentally obfuscated: ```{a[NR]=b[$1]++}NR>FNR&&a[FNR]``` would have been easier to understand and the same number of bytes...

Comment: Working TIO (uses bash, but you can manually edit the title): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnJ@Saqv@vzoxWls7L9Y2KVrFMFZbuzbPzs0vSE0NJJob@1@dKzU5I19B3VDBSMFYwUTBVMFMwVzBQsFSXcFOwccQKguSMwbKmQJVGAPlDcGyRlyJ5dkKumUKQcG26grqCkoqICuVgBJAnf8B "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: by just casually reading, don't you just treat the first test case where the first tist is 1 to 9 in order? Does it really work with the other test cases?

Comment: on a second reading... it seems to work. very clever!

Comment: @Jonah - Thanks very much for showing how to do this on TIO!  That's perfect!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>44</s></sup> 43 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string).

```hs
x!y=[a|(i,a)<-zip[0..]x,y!!i`elem`take i y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY/daoNAEIXv8xQrBKJwTJ1df5PY@0LfQIQsZEmXbFSMF0npu9vRVij0tpSBhfnOObMzb/p2Mc6N4917lJX@8C10cAjfbVdF2219x8Pz7NE4cz0O@mKEFY96vGrbiFKc2pUQHGg5cOt04z@VG7EJDuvnsxlebWNYdmbwHcHJoFws@01gWel62wxrvzf6JBztdtVLM5iz6evAm6E/aOsEB39KZTlLp77thBJtwHOmZcaKIKEQI0GKDDmKel9NRDFJmCumVIswFNWEsnrFES62zdEviankTs6UlsAEVlVIiFgjqeIkZcPcT89i@lZWv3cBRSAexx4FikEJKAXxRjmogOS5nOFvFGQMmUCmkBlkDllARVAExSP5Gj4kgUqhMqgcqkAcLbv@XS0H/eMNnw)

### How?

```hs
x!y=                        -- (!) is a function that takes lists x and y as input
    [a|                     -- and returns the list of all the elements a
    (i,a)<-zip[0..]x,       -- where a is the i-th element of x
    y!!i`elem`take i y]     -- and the i-th element of y is not a "first occurrence" in y
```

Comment: -1 if you rearrange `(a,i)<-zip x[0..]` to `(i,a)<-zip[0..]x`

Comment: @UnrelatedString How did I miss that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a.filter((_,i)=>b.indexOf(b[i])<i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY9BasMwEEX3OYkEP8YzI8k21LlCD2BMcRI7KBi7JCHk9u6oLV00XgaBFk9/nv6cu3t3PVzi5207zcd@Geqlq3f7etdlQxxv/cWYD0SrKIvTsX@8D2bfxNa@Rbsc5uk6j302ziczmIbAEDh4BBQoUbXWNAmJIq8PophaazdPg5T4r2ElwMr5J0Crhi0h1wyxOB9S8Buka/W7fz1BOUjFKhCQA3lQAGnZElSBVa0zWkHADuzBAVyAS3AFySEEUaUuqjt6SIAUkBJSweV/tV930k7LFw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io/), 67 bytes

```
$[a b][loop reverse unique map b'x[index b x]'i[remove.index'a i]a]
```

[Try it on the Arturo Playground!](https://arturo-lang.io/playground/?vENS7f#)

Comment: Great! The entire Arturo site + Playground looks good - I might start learning :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 69 bytes

```
func[a b][foreach c unique b[change at a index? find b c none]trim a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZA5bsQwDEV7n@JdIIApek2TC0yVVmDhRc64iCcxxkBu73AwdpkuIqDlkZ@f0JrG/T2N0bLplX3aliF29Ban25q64crAtszfW6KPw7VbPhLdnY55GdPPG5Of9F603JZk93X@pLP91MaLcAkWM3xFIaAUlFTUNLRGfBB1UjpXp2JnrYcdmoMFvwc7c0/2IuSOJWhRVna8H5v94YnkiOtdo0iBlEiFuHODtATv5ho3UkJBKAkVoSY0hBbNUUG9pU/tA5dohdZog7YU@Tnc/4VlFr/WW5@YeH7m/gs)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ÞU†Tİ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%9EU%E2%80%A0T%C4%B0&inputs=%5B2%2C3%2C3%2C5%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D&header=&footer=)

Same as the APL and Jelly answer.

### Explained

```
ÞU†Tİ
ÞU    # unique mask over second list
  †   # vectorised not over that
   Tİ # and index the truthy indices into the first list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
DÙõ.;.ïÏ
```

I have the feeling this could be shorter, but 05AB1E's builtin might not be the most suitable for this challenge.

\$L2\$ as first input, \$L1\$ as second.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5fDMw1v1rPUOrz/c//9/tJGOMRCaAqEJkDbXMYzlijbUAYmaAMXMgCIWOpaxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##rZAxCsJAFESvElKPIf//3U2CRRpvsSyoYGFlERByAVvBzlNYeYLcxIvESYJgYSkDu8sbZnf2n7rd/ngYz32bZ6/LLcvbftuNm@E@PIt1MTyG64gxxqgwylOOewVJiIKJOrJAUqNJCVlc8GxTHyRzQmnpglaCEtNCPJ8VouZ8@Er8T7/aQkoIPT5sEAfxkADh32pIA2UlZljYoA7qoQFaQWtoAythAuOVnAtH4mEBVsFqWANXppTe).

**Explanation:**

```python
D         # Duplicate the first (implicit) input-list L2
 Ù        # Uniquify the values in the copied list
  õ.;     # Replace the first occurrences of the values in L2 to an empty string
     .ï   # Check for each item whether it's an integer (1 if an integer; 0 if an empty
          # string)
       Ï  # Only keep the values at the truthy indices in the (implicit) input-list L1
          # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c=[],i=0:i<len(a)and f(a,b,c+[a[i]]*(b.index(b[i])!=i),i+1)or c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5LDsIwDET3nMLsEjog0rTlI3KSKIukHxGpBIRYwOmDQ4UtjeznseXH53W9J53zZGZ/C4Mnj4DeWIdo9ud4mcckvPRpoEn8RpX1Njq3EWEX0zC@ReBWrk2UiJWS9yf1eWL1oEAxkRVWoYZGgxYdDjji5GAL0Uxa5pqpchJUrJwOtOwsrOayXpj6@7YKe8aq1k3b8blfX8RJd14Rx@MZ00uUpylIucpf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩΦθ›κ⌕η§ηκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zpyS1SKNQR8G9KDURxMzWUXDLzEvRyNBRcCzxzEtJrQAxszXBwPr//@hoQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdcx0LHctYnWiQiDFQxBQobgwUNYyN/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @tsh's JavaScript answer.

```
  θ         First list
 Φ          Filtered where
    κ       Current index
   ›        Is greater than
     ⌕      First index of
         κ  Current index
       §    Element of
        η   Second list
      η     In second list
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[x for x,y in zip(a,b)if b==(b:={*b}-{y})]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU/RaoNAEHzvV9yjhgm4u3d6BvwS64NSpEJrRPIQE/LtdiIUGp/LwsHN7MzOTMvl8zxanOa1r97Xr/a7@2hdi@5UX11/nt0VixtGdxumhGg69K6rqqQ7VfdD9zjel0farNM8jJekT2qBwuARkKNARNmgfiJGJBA3otKk6dsfBYdbm/KFUSK6MbLTHAUZSVHzIefG9n8@O@ddFkgGoReVBvGQAMkhTBQhJZSe1PCoQT00QHNoAY3QEpbBBEZLtmGRAMthBSzCSvjsN@j/DcusPw)

A little better

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
M!-m←ηk¹ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/31dRN/dR24Rz27MP7Tza8P///2hdQx0DHRARC2Ub6RgaGZuYmsUCAA)

### Explanation

```
M!-m←ηk¹ŀ
      k   key
     η     the indices of each element on their value.
   m←     take the first index of each key
  -       remove this from
        ŀ the input, converted to indices.
M         map each index to
 !         the respective element in the second array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 108 bytes

```python
k={y.index(x)for x in y};n='z=[v for i,v in enumerate(z)if i not in k]';exec(n);n=n.replace("z","y");exec(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvBCsIwEATQu1@x5NINhEKtIlLyJaWHUrcaWrclxpJE/PaYHmQOA2@YNbjHwnWKoGE2L4e25zthpa5SHkLG9qjqnHPOKfdFVV2a9CeUhm/k0ctxseDBMIRvw7qIut1gN6O2XYnfT7K9I4zSjGCAF7f71BUNeRqQZb5xaWmd@4FQRKFEEPI/ptUadhhVkOkH)

Define two lists z and y

Comment: Assuming two predefined variables is **not** an allowed I/O format.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>8</strike> 7 bytes

```
.DExLQ{
```

Input is L2 and L1, separated by newlines

-1 because Pyth has a built-in for evaluated input I forgot about

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8/FtcInsPr//2gjHWMgNAVCEyBtrmMYyxVtqAMSNQGKmQFFLHQsY//lF5Rk5ucV/9dNAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
#[[Union@@Rest/@PositionIndex@#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY4xa8NADIV3/4qCwdMLtaS7sz003JottHQyHkzqUA@5QHxDwFz@uiu77dK5CAT6pPf0Ln38HC59HE/9cn5Z8rZ9D@M1eP86TPHZH6/TGHU@hI/h7nPuumI53sYQ23y3P3ufd8Xj7dSHx5zNM4EhMLBwqFCjScie5pWJMqsbUU5J8XqstR1ssm@4I5Q6EYuxbltuZG2/qj8vQCVInVQkIAOyIAfSNzWoAaudahgsYAO2YAeuwDW4gZQQgqilRtR0FuIgFaSGNDDlT7x/rZSytHwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
sub{my%s;grep$s{+shift}++,@{+shift}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVFta4MwEP7urwjitkqfgZcYXyZl/o@uDAbaubXq1MFK6W93Z2o7O/pxLIHk8rxccpc6aza63@6cfNG3ny/77e6mTdZNVjvtft6@Fnl3mM@RnuJDn1h51cwswWNpVrEkSCj40AgQIkK8wsgMuGJcM6uYozMzoOHKHEbsJxtNdCb3@XTVIFkiJ4apfWCuee4JHttIKl8HZ7VBh2XiHyXXX/qrbpAH4uvZpUA@SIMCENcdgWJIvpI9/CYF6UNqyAAyhIwgYygPiqA4JfeM26WhAqgQKoKK4XuXFf7dvPisfyvm2E/L3Ztgu5s5m6LtCGaTcLKv2l2kznMy8um66ha3Tn7SpUehe@Trpig78VYV5ewOdxjErsg@JohJKB6FXb3b4kHYZdUJDiHsp9JOrEP/DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 44 bytes

```arturo
$[a,b][i:0select a=>[in? b\[i]take b i'i+1]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?IMFklu)

```
$[a,b][                    ; a function taking two lists a and b
    i:0                    ; set i to 0
    select a=>[            ; select elements from a where...
        in? b\[i]take b i  ; the ith element of b is found in b's elements that come before index i
        'i+1               ; increment i
    ]                      ; end select
]                          ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
gVðÏÀVbX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z1bwz8BWYlg&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5XQpbMiAzIDMgNSA1IDQgMyA3IDFd)

```
kÏ¶VbVgY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=a8%2b2VmJWZ1k&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5XQpbMiAzIDMgNSA1IDQgMyA3IDFd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 3 bytes

```
▽¬◰
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4pa9wqzil7AKCmYgWzIgMyAzIDUgNSA0IDMgNyAxXSBbMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYgNyA4IDldCmYgWzEgMiAzXSBbMSAxIDFdCmYgWzEgMSAxXSBbMiAyIDJdCg==)